# 2 Different Services with the Same Base Object

Tags: .net, web-services

I have 2 services that one returns an object and a second service that takes that same object in as a paramater. Is it possible to do something like the following in .NET? From my understanding JAVA actually supports actions like this

```
var personObject = Service1.GetPerson();

Service2.DeletePerson(personObject);
```

Thank you for any assistance or direction that can be provided!

Comment: What kind of "service" are you talking about?

Comment: The services are Java, so WCF is out.

Comment: Just a little more, the objects are the same they just aren't viewed that way because of the Web Reference WSDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually [shared types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480505.aspx) on the reference. Doesn't appear to have a permanent solution for it that you will not have to update after each update of the wsdl but it works.